# Nested routes question in NestJS RESTful API

Tags: api, rest, design-patterns, nestjs, backend

I am designing a RESTful API in NestJS for a project and I am struggling on how to handle the nested routes. Here is an overview:

- The authentication is handled in the frontend by Firebase. The token is sent to the API to be verified, which happens in a middleware. Upon success, the user ID from firebase is attached to the request and forwarded.
- Each user can create multiple pet profiles, living under the `/profiles` endpoint. All CRUD operations are supported.
- Each pet profile can have various resources related to them, notes for example.
- All of the resource types are separated by Nest modules, which contain the entity, service, etc.

Here we reach the part that I can't wrap my mind around. It would make sense to nest the resource as `/profiles/:profileId/notes`.
Subsequent nesting, e.g. a specific note, would be `/profiles/:profileId/notes/:noteId` and so on. CRUD operations would also be handled there.
What bothers me is that going with this approach, I will end up having a single controller for the entire app - the Profiles contoller.

Another approach I considered was having the `GET ALL` and `POST` methods under the Profiles controller, and `GET`, `PUT` and `DELETE` under a module specific controller - e.g. `/notes/:noteId`. But in that case I don't know how to protect those sub-resources, as I wouldn't have the profileId available this way - and I wouldn't know if the caller owns the profile, so that I can authorize those operations.

How would you handle this issue? Thanks for the replies.